# How are we to understand כל עדת בנ״י

Tags: torah-study, parashat-shelach

Especially in this week’s Parsha, shelach, but also throughout all of tanach, how are we to understand the statement כל עדת בנ״י and other similar statements referring to the Jewish nation as a whole? Does this refer to a simple majority? What is the threshold of people that would warrant the torah describing the entire nation as acting or feeling a certain way, or saying something?

Comment: very similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38722/170